# Type checking styled-components props in stateless component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I followed the styled-components [docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#typescript) regarding TypeScript and React stateless components, however I'm still getting a type check error in my props when creating the styled component.

This is my component code:

```js
import { StatelessComponent } from 'react'
import styled, { css, keyframes } from 'styled-components'

interface IProps {
  altStyle?: boolean
  className?: string
  name: string
  type?: string
}

const PrimaryButton: StatelessComponent<IProps> = (props) =>
  <button className={props.className} type={props.type}>
    <span>
      {props.name}
    </span>
  </button>

PrimaryButton.defaultProps = {
  altStyle: false,
  type: 'button',
}

const hoverAnimation = keyframes`
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  } to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
`

const StyledPrimaryButton = styled(PrimaryButton)`
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #b60c41, #b30d41, #51213c);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 45px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 0 28px;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  > span {
    position: relative;
  }
  &:before {
    background: #51213c;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  &:hover:before {
    animation: ${hoverAnimation} 2s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  }
  ${(props) => props.altStyle && css`
    background: transparent;
    border: solid 2px #fff;
    transition: background 1s ease;
    &:hover {
      background: #b60c41;
      border: none;
      padding: 0 30px;
    }
    &:hover:before {
      animation-delay: 1s;
    }
  `}
`

export default StyledPrimaryButton
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

> components/buttons/PrimaryButton.tsx(60,5): error TS2345: Argument of type '(props: ThemedStyledProps) => false | InterpolationValue[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interpolation>'.
>   [0]   Type '(props: ThemedStyledProps) => false | InterpolationValue[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReadonlyArray | InterpolationFunct...'.
>   [0]     Property 'concat' is missing in type '(props: ThemedStyledProps) => false | InterpolationValue[] | undefined'.

If I add `props: any`, everything builds as expected, however I would like to find a better solution in order not to clutter my components with a lot of `props: any`.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: The code you posted compiles as expected (with no errors) using latest react, styled-components and TS compiler

Comment: Weird. I'm also on the latest version of the above packages. However, I have omitted that I'm using Next.js for server side rendering. Maybe this is causing issues?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, this was my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

I set `"strict": false` and now I am experiencing the expected behaviour, no errors when omitting `: any`. Everything else is working as normal.